# JAVA Override interface method with abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to ask whether we should override interfaceMethod? Is this a good or bad habbit?

```
    public interfaceA {
       interfaceMethod();
    }
    public abstract classB implement interfaceA {
       @override
       public abstract interfaceMethod();
    }
```

or we should just do nothing there?

```
   public interfaceA {
       interfaceMethod();
    }
    public abstract classB implement interfaceA {
           
        }
```

Comment: Just do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Both are right but it seems the second option is better because with modern IDEs is very easy to know for a developer which methods will need to be implemented by subclasses of ClassB, so we are not getting a great advantage adding explicitly an empty declaration

Answer (score -1):

The only difference is that, in the first snippet, you have to type 38% more. I did the maths.